# c#/quartz - passing class as parameter of function

Tags: c#, class, parameters, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have the following code, which creates a job and trigger, and then schedules the job with Quartz:

```
public void ScheduleJob<T>(string jobName, string jobGroup, string triggerName, string triggerGroup)
{
    var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
    var jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, jobGroup);
    var job = JobBuilder.Create<T>()
        .WithIdentity(jobKey)
        .StoreDurably()
        .Build();
    var jobTrigger = QuartzConstraints.QuartzCreateTrigger(triggerName, triggerGroup);
    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, jobTrigger);
    scheduler.Start();
}
```

I want to pass in the name of a class as `T` to this function, i.e. a class like:

```
class DeletionJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
      // code here
    }
}
```

I read some pages on passing classes as parameters, but I am unable to figure out how to do it in this case. I get an error that

> The type 'T' must be convertible to 'Quartz.IJob' in order to use it
>   as a parameter 'T' in the generic method 'JobBuilder
>   Quartz.JobBuilder.Create()'

Not sure how to resolve this. Is there a better way to pass the class as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you need to add a type constraint to your method, so the compiler will know how to call `JobBuilder.Create<T>()`. Like this:

```
public void ScheduleJob<T>(string jobName, string jobGroup, string triggerName, string triggerGroup) where T: IJob
{ ... }
```

And later call it like this:

```
ScheduleJob<DeletionJob>(...);
```

You can read more about constraints [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)